# IIS 7 native module issues

Tags: iis, module, native

I am currently working on migrating our ISAPI filters to IIS modules. In our ISAPI filter we have both HttpFilterProc() and HttpExtensionProc() defined and each has a different code flow.

The module is responsible for displaying login page and authenticate the user account (the login page is displayed based on the URL the user is accessing.)

I have now OnBeginRequest(), OnAuthenticateREquest() etc. defined in the module. I am able to display the login page, but the problem is that all the notifications (OnBeginRequest() to OnEndRequest()) are called immediately and does not wait for the actual completion of authenticating the user account.

The destructor of CHttpModule derived class is called before the user enters the credentials and try to authenticate the account.

Should this be handled with another set of OnBeginRequest() to OnEndRequest(). I have read about CloneContext() and ExecuteRequest(). Should I be creating a child request by cloning the context?

Regards,
George

Comment: George, each time a page is requested, all subscribed events (OnBeginRequest, OnAuthenticateRequest, etc.) are fired.  When the user goes to the login page, that's one request.   When they type in their info and press submit, that's another request.  Your custom module won't wait for the user to enter their credentials and then continue where you want it to; you need to handle the request properly depending on your custom business rules.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, I still have some queries. If I understand correctly, the HttpExtensionProc() is called when the user click on a button in a form or so. When processing the user credentials from the login page, I do not want to have the code inside BeginRequest() to be executed and just want to return from it. What i needed is to execute the code inside OnExecuteRequestHandler(). However, I need to figure out a way to determine that I need not do the processing in OnBeginRequest when user credentials are authenticated.

Comment: So the question becomes, how do you know whether or not the user has been authenticated?  What kind of authentication are you using?  And how are you able to access that authentication information from within a native module?

Comment: We have a back end java code which can determine, whether the user is authenticated or not. From my native module, I have to direct the request in the right way which I can do now.

Comment: However, I face another issue now. In the back end java code on tomcat, we call HttpServletRequest::getParameterValues() to get to know the value of the fields on the login page. (like user_name, user_pasword etc.) The problem is these values comes as null value. I am not sure why this is happening and I would like to debug by querying these values from native module, prior to redirecting it to tomcat/java code.Which function I can use to query these values like "user_name" available in the login page from the native module?